# What are ResourceContainers and how to use them for Cloud Endpoints?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Since Google AppEngine 1.8.5 there is a new warning in the development environment:

```
WARNING  2013-09-27 10:10:53,035 api_config.py:1768] Method specifies path
parameters but you are not using a ResourceContainer. This will fail in future
releases; please switch to using ResourceContainer as soon as possible.
```

What are ResourceContainers and how to use them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They recently updated the docs to explain this change here: [Google App Engine Docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/create_api#using_resourcecontainer_for_path_or_querystring_arguments)

Basically what you want to do is to separate the request body and the query/path parameters.

The request body will be a normal `messages.Message` class and you define any additional parameters in the `ResourceContainer`.

```
YOUR_RESOURCE_CONTAINER = endpoints.ResourceContainer(
        MyRequestBodyMessagesClass,
        parameter1=messages.IntegerField(2, required=True)
        parameter2=messages.StringField(3))
```

This change should help to minimize the amount of necessary Message classes because you can mostly reuse the RequestBody-Message for Response-Messages as well.

Note: if you are using the [endpoints-proto-datastore](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-proto-datastore) there's an [open issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-proto-datastore/issues/79) about this.