# Different classes for request and response

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints-proto-datastore

I've just started using Proto Datastore to create an API. I'd like to know whether it is possible to have different classes for my request and response, provided both are inherited from EndpointsModel. For example,

```
class my_request(EndpointsModel):
    #attributes

class my_response(EndpointsModel):
    #different set of attributes

@endpoints.api(name='Blah', version='v1')
    class testAPI(remote.Service):

    @my_request.method(name='myAPImethod', path='blah',
                      http_method='POST')
    def myAPImethod(self, req):
        #do something
        resp = my_response()
        return resp
```

This doesn't look like it would work. So could someone please tell me how to create such a method. The only other way I can think of is to revert to the original protorpc method and specifiy both request and response types as part of the decorator. Is there a way to achieve this using proto-datastore?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a sort of input/output field [filtering using `request_fields=` and `response_fields=` in your `.method()`](http://endpoints-proto-datastore.appspot.com/examples/custom_api_response_messages.html) decorator but you cannot specify different input and output message classes.

You will have to use the standard endpoints and protoRPC classes and decorators if you need to use different objects.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you have a very simple layout that doesn't really jibe with the question asked or, IMHO, with what I think it is that you are actually wanting to ask.

I'm working on an Endpoints API myself that is much more complicated but uses two different models to craft both the request and response objects for my API calls; they are, however, nested one (or more) within the other. I found the hint that led me to the method that should be used as a warning in the App Engine Logs:

```
Method csapi.user.XXXXX specifies path parameters but you are not using a ResourceContainer. This will fail in future releases; please switch to using ResourceContainer as soon as possible.
```

**Take note**; ResourceContainers can be quite tricky and require you to class off of `messages.Message` which you would import from protorpc. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048440/what-are-resourcecontainers-and-how-to-use-them-for-cloud-endpoints) StackOverflow answer for an explanation of ResourceContainers.

Using your example as a base, we need to build ResourceContainers that duplicate what is in the model that we wish to be returned to the callee.

```python
import endpoints
from protorpc import messages
from protorpc import message_types
from protorpc import remote
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.ext.ndb import msgprop
from endpoints_proto_datastore.ndb import EndpointsAliasProperty
from endpoints_proto_datastore.ndb import EndpointsModel

class MySubscriptionResponseMessage(messages.Message):
    id = messages.IntegerField(1)
    accountType = messages.EnumField(Account_Type, 2, required=True)
    isActive = messages.BooleanField(3, required=True, default=False)
    thisAcctEmail = messages.StringField(4)
    subscriberSince = message_types.DateTimeField(5)

class MyUserResponseMessage(messages.Message):
    id = messages.IntegerField(1)
    subscriptions = messages.MessageField('SubscriptionReadResponseMessage', 2, repeated=True)

class MySubscription(EndpointsModel):
    accountType = msgprop.EnumProperty(AccountType, choices=set([AccountType.POTENTIAL_LEAD, AccountType.BASIC, AccountType.ADVANCED, AccountType.PREMIUM]), required=True, default=AccountType.POTENTIAL_LEAD)
    isActive = ndb.BooleanProperty(required=True, indexed=True)
    thisAcctId = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=False, indexed=True, required=True)
    subscriberSince = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class MyUser(EndpointsModel):
    subscription_key = ndb.KeyProperty(kind="Subscription", repeated=True)
    def IdSet(self, value):
        # By default, the property "id" assumes the "id" will be an integer in a
        # simple key -- e.g. ndb.Key(GSModel, 10) -- which is the default behavior
        # if no key is set. Instead, we wish to use a string value as the "id" here,
        # so first check if the value being set is a string.
        if not isinstance(value, basestring):
            raise TypeError('ID must be a string.')
        # We call UpdateFromKey, which each of EndpointsModel.IdSet and
        # EndpointsModel.EntityKeySet use, to update the current entity using a
        # datastore key. This method sets the key on the current entity, attempts to
        # retrieve a corresponding entity from the datastore and then patch in any
        # missing values if an entity is found in the datastore.
        self.UpdateFromKey(ndb.Key(Csuser, value))

    @EndpointsAliasProperty(setter=IdSet, required=True)
    def id(self):
        # First check if the entity has a key.
        if self.key is not None:
            # If the entity has a key, return only the string_id. The method id()
            # would return any value, string, integer or otherwise, but we have a
            # specific type we wish to use for the entity "id" and that is string.
            return self.key.string_id()

    @EndpointsAliasProperty(repeated=True,property_type=Subscription.ProtoModel())
    def subscriptions(self):
    return ndb.get_multi(self.subscription_key)

@endpoints.api(name='Blah', version='v1')
    class testAPI(remote.Service):

    @my_request.method(
        response_message=MyUserResourceContainer,
        name='myAPImethod', 
        path='blah',
        http_method='POST')
    def myAPImethod(self, req):
        #do something
        this_sub = MySubscription()
        subs = []

        ... how you manipulate this object is up to you ...

        for sub in subs
            sub_msg = MySubscriptionResponseMessage(
                id=this_sub.id, 
                accountType=this_sub.accountType, 
                isActive=this_sub.isActive, 
                thisAcctEmail=this_sub.thisAcctEmail, 
                subscriberSince=this_sub.subscriberSince, 
            subs.append(sub_msg)

        return MyUserResponseMessage(
            id=user1.id, 
            subscriptions=subs)
```

As you can see this is quite a bit more in depth than your simple example.

**Bonus Points:** Using Path Parameters

If you were to wish to accept path parameters for your method such as our hypothetical user's id property (ie, `path='users/{id}/delete'`), we would add the following block preceding the method itself where it will be used:

```python
MY_REQUEST_RESOURCE_PAGE = endpoints.ResourceContainer(
    message_types.VoidMessage,
    id=messages.StringField(1, variant=messages.Variant.STRING),
    accountType=messages.EnumField(Account_Type, 2, required=True)
    isActive=messages.BooleanField(3, required=True),
    thisAcctEmail=messages.StringField(4, variant=messages.Variant.STRING),
    subscriberSince=messages.message_types.DateTimeField(5),
    cursor=messages.StringField(6, variant=messages.Variant.STRING, required=False, default="1"),
    limit=messages.IntegerField(7, variant=messages.Variant.INT32, required=False, default=10)
)
```

**Note:** Notice the additional properties `cursor` and `limit`, they allow pagination of the returned results for cases where you have hundreds of users; these are used frequently in model queries for just this purpose.

Now, to complete the changes for accepting path parameter replace this line from my example above:

```
response_message=MyUserResponseMessage,
```

With this one:

```
MY_REQUEST_RESOURCE_PAGE , MyUserResponseMessage,
```

On a final note, this setup - whether using path parameters or not - allows you to nest one or more `MySubscriptionResponseMessage` items inside your `MyUserResponseMessage` to return to the callee just as the `MyUser` model may contain multiple `MySubscription` models. This does not require adding anything to your api method as it is already a nest item in `MyUserResponseMessage`. Also, You do not need to duplicate items from your model in your response messages if those items do not need to be returned to the callee.