# Deployed Google Endpoints Quickstart app giving error message when i request url?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, openapi

I am following the Quickstart for Cloud Endpoints Frameworks on App Engine in standard environment. I have deployed the sample API. When I open https://[my-project].appspot.com/ I get the error message:

```
Error: Not Found. The Requested URL / was not found on this server
```

The logs show the message:

```
No Handlers matched this url
```

The app.yaml handlers are the what came with the endpoints-frameworks-v2/echo sample:

```
  handlers:
# The endpoints handler must be mapped to /_ah/api.
- url: /_ah/api/.*
  script: main.api
```

I was having great difficulty generating the OpenAPI configuration file in a previous step of the quickstart. I got it to work by updating the system variable path for the SDK but I did get this error:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "endpoints.apiserving"
WARNING:root:Method echo.echo_path_parameter specifies path parameters buy you are
not using a ResourceContainer. This will fail in future releases; please
switch to using ResourceContainer as soon as possible.
```

I have no idea if this error is relavant to the current problem.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The 404 is expected - the sample handlers don't have an entry for the `/` path. Try one of your endpoints paths, maybe something like `https://[PROJECT-ID].appspot.com/_ah/api/echo/v1/echo`?

Comment: Thanks you're right about the 404. When I try the above path however I get a not found message. Also in the next part of the quickstart, when I send a request to the sample API using curl I get a 503 - Internal Server Error response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a url handler for `/` if that is a valid url:

```
handlers:
# The endpoints handler must be mapped to /_ah/api.
- url: /_ah/api/.*
  script: main.api

- url: /.*            # catchall for all other urls
  script: main.api    # or wherever you handle the request for `/` and others
```

Comment: Thankyou I realised it needed to be included when I searched the URL that Dan suggested above:  ''https://[PROJECT-ID].appspot.com/_ah/api/echo/v1/echo''. When I try this URL however I get a not found message. Also in the next part of the quickstart, when I send a request to the sample API using curl I get a 503 - Internal Server Error response. Any idea what might be going on now?

Comment: You're going to have to post some code for the handler.  Does a request to `/` also return a 503?

Comment: I will mark this question as answered and open up a new question that is more specific. Thanks again

Comment: @Nicholas - I ran into, and solved the second problem you reported. Can you link the new question and if it's unanswered I'll answer?

Comment: @Jack - I never did post the question but I have now. Any help would be great thanks. [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42520630/google-cloud-endpoints-python-quickstart-echo-sample-issue)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the "No handlers could be found for logger..." you need to do this:
http://excid3.com/blog/no-handlers-could-be-found-for-logger

The other issue is a known issue:
[What are ResourceContainers and how to use them for Cloud Endpoints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048440/what-are-resourcecontainers-and-how-to-use-them-for-cloud-endpoints)